# How to filter with recursion in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, recursion, tail-recursion

How to filter with recursion in Ruby?

Say you have an array of objects, that have a property, which can have one of two values. If it's the first value - keep the first occurance of the object, if it is the second value - keep the last occurance of the object. Let's give an example:

```
# type can be :foo or :bar
MyObject = Struct.new(:id, :type)

a = MyObject.new(1, :foo)
b = MyObject.new(2, :foo)
c = MyObject.new(3, :bar)
d = MyObject.new(4, :bar)
e = MyObject.new(5, :foo)
f = MyObject.new(6, :bar)
```

So if it is `:foo`, keep the first occurance and discard all following (until you reach a `:bar`), if it's a `:bar`, discard all but the last occurance (until you reach `:foo`)

```
# given the initial collection looks like this:
[a, b, c, d, e, f]

# this must be the result after filtering:
[a, d, e, f]
```

I used iteration to solve this:

```
initial_collection = [a, b, c, d, e, f]

initial_collection.each_with_object([initial_collection.first]) do |item, filtered_collection|
  if filtered_collection.last.type != item.type
    filtered_collection.push(item)
  elsif item.type == :bar
    filtered_collection[-1] = item
  end
end
```

I have problems understanding how to do this with recursion. Particularly, I can't wrap my head around how to both keep track of the previous and the next item. What would be a recursive solution?

Comment: The way you keep track of state in recursion is by passing it down as a parameter. If the state is internal only, you create the "real" recursive implementation and have your public facing function call it with the right parameters. Function recursion isn't that useful in most imperative languages though because they tend to have poor support for optimizing recursive patterns.

Comment: The recursion is not applicable here. Well, one might fake it, but in fact, the recursion is a tool to walk through _nested_ structures.

Comment: @mudasobwa, recursion is a mathematical tool, it has nothing to do with nesting. It might be a bad tool for the stated problem though. But everything is good for a homework.

Comment: @Yossi recursion is neither a tool (it’s a process,) nor pure mathematical (it has it’s applications almost [everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).) In the first place, recursion can not be applied to plain list. There is no entry point for the subsequent call to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing `:foo` requires knowing the previous element, while processing `:bar` requires knowing the next; so at any given point in a recursion, we must look at a three element window from which we might add the middle element to our result.

Here's some pattern-matching pseudocode (`null` means there is no element in that cell of the window, `_` matches anything; note that the order of match cases matters):

```
f([:foo, :foo, _]) ->
  f(next_window)

f([_, :foo, _]) ->
  [middle_element] + f(next_window)

f([_, :bar, :bar]) ->
  f(next_window)

f([_, :bar, _]) ->
  [middle_element] + f(next_window)

// End of list
f([_, null, null]) ->
  []
```

Here's a Ruby version:

```rb
def f(list, middle_index)
  window = get_window(list, middle_index)

  if window[0,2] == [:foo, :foo]
    f(list, middle_index + 1)

  elsif window[1] == :foo
    [list[middle_index]] +
    f(list, middle_index + 1)

  elsif window[1,2] == [:bar, :bar]
    f(list, middle_index + 1)

  elsif window[1] == :bar
    [list[middle_index]] +
    f(list, middle_index + 1)

  # End of list
  elsif window[1,2] == [nil, nil]
    []
  end
end

def get_window(list, middle_index)
  [maybe_type(list, middle_index - 1),
   maybe_type(list, middle_index),
   maybe_type(list, middle_index + 1)]
end

def maybe_type(list, index)
  if index < 0 or list[index].nil?
    nil
  else
    list[index].type
  end
end
```

Output:

```
MyObject = Struct.new(:id, :type)

a = MyObject.new(1, :foo)
b = MyObject.new(2, :foo)
c = MyObject.new(3, :bar)
d = MyObject.new(4, :bar)
e = MyObject.new(5, :foo)
f = MyObject.new(6, :bar)
g = MyObject.new(7, :bar)

arr = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]

puts f(arr, 0).inspect
# [#<struct MyObject id=1, type=:foo>,
#  #<struct MyObject id=4, type=:bar>,
#  #<struct MyObject id=5, type=:foo>,
#  #<struct MyObject id=7, type=:bar>]
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursion must receive an extra argument to keep track of the current state, we use `type` for it.

```
def recursive_filter(objects, type=nil)
  return [] if objects.empty?  # Stop condition
  first = objects.shift

  if first.type == type
    recursive_filter(objects, first.type)
  else
    [first] + recursive_filter(objects, first.type)
  end
end
```

Comment: @mudasobwa, Quoting wiki you've provided _Recursion occurs when a thing is defined in terms of itself or of its type_. This function falls under that definition perfectly well.

Comment: Yes, I was plain wrong. Apologies. Actually, all operations on plain lists in functional paradigm in languages like Erlang/LISP would be done with exactly this pattern (yet in way more pleasant syntax.)

Comment: @Yossi, thank you very much for the explanation, I hadn't thought of this this way. However, the code you provided doesn't yield the expected result - instead of returning [a, d, e, f], it returns [a, c, e, f] - so it always takes the first occurrence, regardless of the type.

Answer (score 1):

I would not think of this problem as one that calls for a recursive solution. I suggest the following method.

**Code**

```
def weed(arr)
  e = [:first, :last].cycle
  first_or_last = e.next
  arr.drop(1).each_with_object([arr.first]) do |x,a|
    if attr_same_as_previous?(x, a.last)
      a[-1] = x if first_or_last == :last
    else
      first_or_last = e.next
      a << x
    end
  end
end

def attr_same_as_previous?(x, previous)
  x[:type] == previous[:type]
end
```

The method `attr_same_as_previous?` isolates the property that determines whether the given attribute has changes, making the solution more robust.

**Examples**

*#1*

```
MyObject = Struct.new(:id, :type)

a = MyObject.new(1, :foo)
b = MyObject.new(2, :foo)
c = MyObject.new(3, :bar)
d = MyObject.new(4, :bar)
e = MyObject.new(5, :foo)
f = MyObject.new(6, :bar)
g = MyObject.new(7, :bar)

arr = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
  #=> [#<struct MyObject id=1, type=:foo>, #<struct MyObject id=2, type=:foo>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=3, type=:bar>, #<struct MyObject id=4, type=:bar>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=5, type=:foo>, #<struct MyObject id=6, type=:bar>]       

weed arr
  #=> [#<struct MyObject id=1, type=:foo>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=4, type=:bar>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=5, type=:foo>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=7, type=:bar>]
```

*#2*

```
MyObject = Struct.new(:id, :type)

a = MyObject.new(1, :cat)
b = MyObject.new(2, :cat)
c = MyObject.new(3, :dog)
d = MyObject.new(4, :dog)
e = MyObject.new(5, :pig)
f = MyObject.new(6, :owl)
g = MyObject.new(7, :owl)

weed [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
  #=> [#<struct MyObject id=1, type=:cat>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=4, type=:dog>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=5, type=:pig>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=7, type=:owl>]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a recursive solution. If you compare it with my other answer you will see that it is a *phony recursion*, a sequential method masked as a recursion. That is due to the nature of the problem.

```
def weed(arr)
  return [] if arr.empty?
  e, *rest = arr
  recurse(rest, [e], :first)
end

def recurse(arr, build, first_or_last)
  e, *rest = arr
  if e[:type] == build.last[:type]
    (build[-1] = e) if first_or_last == :last
  else
    first_or_last = (first_or_last == :first ? :last : :first)
    build << e
  end
  rest.empty? ? build : recurse(rest, build, first_or_last)
end
```

```
MyObject = Struct.new(:id, :type)
a = MyObject.new(1, :foo)
b = MyObject.new(2, :foo)
c = MyObject.new(3, :bar)
d = MyObject.new(4, :bar)
e = MyObject.new(5, :foo)
f = MyObject.new(6, :bar)
g = MyObject.new(7, :bar)

arr = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
  #=> [#<struct MyObject id=1, type=:foo>, #<struct MyObject id=2, type=:foo>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=3,  type=:bar>, #<struct MyObject id=4, type=:bar>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=5, type=:foo>, #<struct MyObject id=6, type=:bar>,
  #    #<struct MyObject id=7, type=:bar>]

weed arr
  #  [#<struct MyObject id=1, type=:foo>,
  #   #<struct MyObject id=4, type=:bar>,
  #   #<struct MyObject id=5, type=:foo>,
  #   #<struct MyObject id=7, type=:bar>]
```